# How to get textarea value displayed based on the selection of other text in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, click, textarea, angular6

I have a main textarea field where I should add one content. I have three other text area fields where I will be displaying some default content. If user clicks a content from any of these three textarea fields, that content should be displayed in the main textarea content field.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
      <textarea #content type="text" class="form-control">   </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4" (click)="setContent(content1.value)">
      <textarea #content1 type="text" name="content" [(ngModel)] = "content4" class="form-control" > Content 1 </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
      <textarea #content2 type="text" name="content5" [(ngModel)] = "content" class="form-control">Content 2
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
      <textarea #content3 type="text" name="content6" [(ngModel)] = "content" class="form-control"> content 3 </textarea>
    </div>
```

How should I get the value & display it in main content. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a lot of ways. Here's one:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  mainContent = '';

  setContent(value) {
    this.mainContent = value;
  }

}
```

Here's your template:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
  <textarea 
    [(ngModel)]="mainContent" 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control">
  </textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
  <textarea 
    #content1 
    type="text" 
    name="content" 
    class="form-control" 
    (click)="setContent(content1.value)">
    Value 1
  </textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
  <textarea 
    #content2 
    type="text" 
    name="content" 
    class="form-control" 
    (click)="setContent(content2.value)">
    Value 2
  </textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
  <textarea 
    #content3 
    type="text" 
    name="content" 
    class="form-control" 
    (click)="setContent(content3.value)">
    Value 3
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byzvtf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for reference. Look at the Lower Part of the template like I've added in this answer.